# Having difficulty solving this integral logic question.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The issue is the second question, $\int^{-2.5}_{0}{(2f(x)-7)}dx$. the first part was simple enough but I can't tell if maybe I'm forgetting a theory that helps solve this or if it is just an extension of the first part.

Let:
$$\int^{2.5}_{-5}{f(x)dx} = 2,\qquad \int^{-2.5}_{-5}{f(x)dx}=7,\qquad \int^{2.5}_{0}{f(x)}dx = 1$$
Find:
$$\int^{0}_{-2.5}{f(x)}dx$$
And:
$$\int^{-2.5}_{0}{(2f(x)-7)}dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{-5}^{2.5} f(x) \, dx &= \int_{-5}^{-2.5} f(x) \, dx + \int_{-2.5}^{0} f(x) \, dx + \int_{0}^{2.5} f(x) \, dx \\
2 &= 7 + \int_{-2.5}^{0} f(x) \, dx + 1 \\
2 &= 8 + \int_{-2.5}^{0} f(x) \, dx \\
\end{align*}

> $$ \int_{-2.5}^{0} f(x) \, dx = -6 $$

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{-2.5} (2f(x)-7) \, dx &= -\int_{-2.5}^{0} (2f(x)-7) \, dx \\
&= \int_{-2.5}^{0} (7 - 2f(x)) \, dx \\
&= 7\int_{-2.5}^{0} dx - 2\int_{-2.5}^{0} f(x) dx \\
&= 7(2.5) - 2(-6) \\
&= 17.5 + 12 \\
&=29.5
\end{align*}

> $$ \int_{0}^{-2.5} (2f(x)-7) \, dx = 29.5 $$

Answer (score 3):

Remember that given $a<c<b$. You have that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ = $\int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx$ + $\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx$.

Apply that to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

For the second part, split it up into two separate integrals and apply linearity:
$$2\int_0^{-2.5}f(x)dx-\int_0^{-2.5}7 dx$$
The second part is readily evaluated:
$$2\int_0^{-2.5}f(x)dx-(7\cdot -2.5-7\cdot 0)$$
$$2\int_0^{-2.5}f(x)dx+17.5$$
Then apply the property $\int_a^b f(x)dx=-\int_b^a f(x)dx$ to change the remaining integral into
$$-2\int_{-2.5}^0f(x)dx+17.5$$
And look! The answer to the first question tells you that $\int_{-2.5}^0 f(x)dx=-6$, so you now have
$$-2(-6)+17.5$$
$$12+17.5$$
$$29.5$$
Let me know if you have any questions about my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $\int_a^b{f(x)\ dx} = -\int_b^a{f(x)\ dx}$ 
and $\int_a^b{c \ dx}=cx|_{x=a}^b=c(b-a)$ if $c$ is a constant